# How can I control the patch in cubase 5?

Tags: midi, cubase, loop

I use cubase and I control my instruments with MIDI. Now I want to know how to control the patch. Specifically I am using a MIDI file where the patch makes a reset where the sound is reset to patch 1.1 at the beginning of the loop and I want to remove that reset when the track loops. How can that be done?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefs > Midi > Reset on stop would be prime candidate, however in a Loop it could actually be any of the 'chase' parameters below that - you may have to experiment.

Without specifics of precisely what is being reset, that's the best I can guess at.

[image]

Comment: It's the patch that is being reset from a manually selected patch to patch 1.1. when the loop starts over. I've updated the question with a screenshot of my MIDI preferences.

Comment: Then you need to move the patch change to outside the loop. Traditional way to do it is to use a distinct setup bar before the track starts to launch non-changing parameters

Comment: It worked. You will get a bounty for it.